# How can I use uconv to convert utf-8 with latin1 and latin2 special characters to latin1 using the transliterate feature?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, converters, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-2

I have to convert an EDIFACT file with unicode (UTF-8) characters (Latin2/iso-8859-2 and latin1/iso-8859-1 special characters) to latin1. 
uconv seems to be the right tool for that but there is no predefined mapping unicode-latin2. Is it possible to create one? How?

Comment: Can a single file contain both characters unique to Latin1 and characters unique to Latin2?  If so, your task seems impossible.  If each file contains only one or the other, than you need to detect which one it is on each file.

Comment: unicode is a superset which includes all character sets. If the file includes only characters of unicode that is mapable to latin1 you can map the characters to latin1 without any problem. But if it includes characters that have to map to latin2 you have a problem. Different solutions are possible: You may map latin2 chracters to similar characters in latin. E.g. you may map

Comment: E.g. you may map the polish "Ł" to "L". Or you may use a question mark for all unknown characters. Or you may omitt all unknown characters. I would like to use the first way called transliteration.

Comment: That's what I want: uconv -f utf8  --callback escape-c |
sed -e 's/\\u0171/ü/g' 
-e 's/\\u0151/ö/g' 
-e 's/\\u2013/-/g' 
-e 's/\\u201D/"/g'